# I live in Taipei, how can I get help by chat in English?

Tags: repair, chat

I would like to use the chatsupport feature. I am in Taipei and my only languages are Math, Python and English. However chatsupport will only converse with me in Chinese.

I walked into Apple Taipei 101 this afternoon to try to get some face-to-face assistance but the place was packed; this is a tourist hot spot and the store was packed and the staff frazzled. I may try to go again Monday, but **my question here is how to use Apple chatsupport in English from a connection in Taiwan?**

I don't have a vpn.

The link provided in the text sends me back to this page again because of course my location is in Taiwan. I see no way easy out of this loop.

[image]

I tried to reply to the e-mail summary that I received after the chat session was complete. It failed (it's no-reply) the error message recommended:

> Thanks for contacting Apple. Messages sent to this email address aren't monitored. Here are links to some Apple websites that you might find helpful.
>
> View your support and service options: getsupport.apple.com/GetSASO

and of course that also will only lead to help in Chinese as well:

[image]

---

fyi the last message (in the short chat exchange below) is in Chinese:

> 很抱歉，因為我們這裡只能是使用中文對談，如果可以的話，我非常願意使用中文與您交流，這是我的工作我非常願意嘗試。

and pasting that into google translate returns:

> Sorry, because we can only use Chinese to talk here, if you can, I am very willing to communicate with you in Chinese. This is my job. I am very willing to try.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you switch the country on the getsupport page and access chat from there?

Comment: @nohillside Oh, now I remember there was a page like that, with the maps, and I started with "US" as my country and by the second click or so it was back in Chinese.

Comment: There should be a flag icon at the bottom of getsupport.apple.com where you can click on the name of the country and select a different one.

Comment: I'll work on that right now, thanks!

Comment: @nohillside aha this is working & I have screenshots. Feel free to write it up if you like, or perhaps it is a duplicate? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the country (and the language) at the bottom of https://getsupport.apple.com/

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! The site tried once more to switch me to Chinese but I fought valiantly and ultimately triumphed ;-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQu4v.png